# DefaultModelBinder incorrectly handles hidden inputs with bool values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I use `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UseOldFormat)` to render bool value which renders into `<input ... type="hidden" value="1" />`
When I submit the form I get UseOldFormat as always false).
Is there any better solution than just doing something like this `@Html.Hidden("UseOldFormat", Model.UseOldFormat?"true":"false")`?

Comment: why use helper? try plain html: <input type="hidden" value="<%= Html.AttributeEncode(model.Id) %>" id="Id" name="Id" />

Comment: I thought that it saves some time. It seems that I was wrong :(

Comment: I tried to use '@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UseOldFormat)' in other project and it renders as '<input ... type="hidden" value="true" />'. What could be wrong with HiddenFor in the first project?

Comment: I figured out what was the problem. 
I have UseOldFormat=1 in get parameters and for some reason @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UseOldFormat) renders its value.

Comment: did hidden.for render input name? PS. For me, the most of time helpers is not the fastes way :)